# What does 'Whitman's poet' in the passage?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I think ***'s***  generally indicates **possession**, but in the following passage, the usage evades me. Does it mean 'Whitman's poetry' or 'a poet like Whitman'?

> Long before Walt Whitman wrote Leaves of Grass, poets had addressed
>   themselves to fame. Horace, Petrarch, Shakespeare, Milton, and Keats
>   all hoped that poetic greatness would grant them a kind of earthly
>   immortality. Whitman held a similar faith that for centuries the world
>   would value his poems. But to this ancient desire to live forever on
>   the page, he added a new sense of fame. Readers would not simply
>   attend to the poet’s work; they would be attracted to the greatness of
>   his personality. They would see in his poems a vibrant cultural
>   performance, an individual springing from the book with tremendous
>   charisma and appeal. Out of the political rallies and electoral
>   parades that marked Jacksonian America, Whitman defined poetic fame in
>   relation to the crowd. Other poets might look for their inspiration
>   from the goddess of poetry. **Whitman’s poet** sought the approval of
>   his contemporaries. In the instability of American democracy, fame
>   would be dependent on celebrity, on the degree to which the people
>   rejoiced in the poet and his work.

*This article is from the preface of **Walt Whitman and the Culture of American Celebrity by David Haven Blake**.*

Comment: I would read it to mean "the poet within Whitman".

Comment: yes, or `Whitman as a poet`

Comment: Hot Licks has it.  Examine the man, Walt Whitman. A  journalist; a newspaper editor; a civil rights activist.  Hated by many.  1848 He  founds & edits his own newpaper  "Free Soil" - Helps  startup  a 3rd US political party.  His printing office is burnt to the ground after first issue. He's a poet; writer; essayist.  critics lambasted both his style, prose construction and content.  Saying "Whitman's poet" is spot on by the writer.